# How to Estimate Google BigQuery cost?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I am trying to estimate cost of linking Google Analytics to BigQuery.
In [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) there are some variable that I need to specify in order to estimate costs, one of them are:

- Active storage
- Long-term storage
- Streaming inserts
- Streaming reads

So could you tell me where can I find this information in Universal Analytics? For instance, what is the size of my active storage?

Answer (score 0):

Just start using it, likely you will be under the free tier for a long time.

Analytics adds a few megabytes of data to your storage, and that's not building up fast. I expect you will have bills around <5 USD even after a year of use.

Comment: I am not an admin to start using it. But I need to estimate the expected costs